# How to recognize if a column is clustered index or non clustered?

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE question2 (
   question_id INT(10) not null auto_increment,
   lesson INT(10) not null,
   questionNum INT(10) not null,
   question varchar(60) not null,
   answer varchar(60) not null,
   primary key (question_id) )
   CHARACTER SET=utf8 ENGINE=InnoDB
```

**First question:** Since I have a primary key column, does it mean I can't have another clustered index?

I write this command

```
ALTER TABLE `question2` ADD INDEX( `lesson`);
```

and now the show create table look like this:

```
question2 | CREATE TABLE `question2` (
`question_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCR
`lesson` int(10) NOT NULL,
`questionNum` int(10) NOT NULL,
`question` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`answer` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`),
KEY `lesson` (`lesson`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

and in php my admin in the index part I can see this:

[image]

I need a clustered index for "lesson" column. becase there is a lot of read query using this column.

**Second question:** So, is "lesson" column a clustered index column or a non clustered index one?

Answer (score 1):

you can have only 1 physical ordering of your table (clustered). You can have scads of secondary indexes. So pick your primary key accordingly. If you have an auto_inc it must be a key (PRIMARY is not required for innodb).

```
show indexes from myTableName;
```

will show PRIMARY (Key_name column) for your primary index.

The following is allowed in InnoDB for auto_increment columns:

```
create table t9
(   col1 int not null primary key,
    col2 int auto_increment,
    key `key099` (col2)
)engine=InnoDB;
```

Note: the auto_increment column is not the primary key as can be shown via

```
show indexes from t9;
```

but it must be a key.

```
create table t10
(   col1 varchar(20) primary key,
    col2 datetime not null,
    col3 int auto_increment,
    key `key101` (col2,col3),
    key `key102` (col3)
)engine=InnoDB;
```

It is `key102` that allows the above to succeed. (As the AI must be a key but it cannot be buried in a composite unless it is left-most).

[How does InnoDB behave without a Primary Key?](https://blog.jcole.us/2013/05/02/how-does-innodb-behave-without-a-primary-key/)

Comment: I don't agree. What you're saying is, that the primary key is always the clustered index?! Can you proof with a link or something? I know it should, but it must??

Comment: He is is asking for multiple clustered indexes. And the assumption is innodb https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html

Comment: Ah, so InnoDB decides what's your clustered index?

Comment: There can be only 1 physical ordering. If you don't choose an index, it synthesizes one for you. Do you want to see a url link to that one?

Comment: I seen it.. mhh okay, seems to be MySQL or InnoDB specific.. wouldn't be my choose of database in this case. But thanks for explaining! :)

Comment: [How does InnoDB behave without a Primary Key?](https://blog.jcole.us/2013/05/02/how-does-innodb-behave-without-a-primary-key/) .... it synthesizes one, which means you always have one

Comment: it says, the auto_increment-column has to be part of an index - it neither says it has to be the index nor it has to be the clustered index. So could it be a part of a non-clustered index and everything is fine? (of course having a clustered index anywhere in the table else)

Comment: AI has to be a primary key, the PK has to be clustered. I have never known an AI not be the PK (unless you fudge it with a trigger in which case it is not truly an AI)

Comment: oh no, maybe I want to have a composite ID with a type AND an AI. There are many cases I needed this...

Comment: wait no i am wrong. Edit performed above for AI issue.